# Building a numpy array through iteration

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I start with an array of shape (n,d) containing n particle-vectors of length *d* dimensions, and want to construct an array containing the inter-particle vectors, of shape (n,n,d) which I'll go on to use for calculating forces etc in a Newtonian simulation.

I want to be able to generalise this for any number of dimensions, so the position vectors could be of any *d*, and have come up with the below, building the new dimension one array at a time into a list that I then convert back into an array. But this seems clunky, and, since it must be such a common operation, I can't help thinking there's some inbuilt numpy magic that will perform this operation more quickly.

```
def delta_matrix(pos_vec):
    build=[]
    for i in pos_vec:
        build.append(i-pos_vec)
    return np.array(build)
```

In particular then, is there a numpy method that performs this iterative type of operation?

Comment: `pos_vec[:,None] - pos_vec`?

Comment: Yes, this is the kind of thing I was looking for - I'm still to fully grasp the finer points of broadcasting - but when I compare results so produced against more traditional iterative approaches, they're blisteringly fast.

Answer (score 2):

What about list comprehension? That seems simple yet powerful enough.

```
def delta_matrix(pos_vec):
    return np.array([i-pos_vec for i in pos_vec])
```

Comment: Thanks Bram, I do like a good list comprehension, but kind of the answer I was looking for is more like the one in @Divakar 's comment above. It takes advantage of numpy broadcasting and having measured the performance between the two, it's consistently faster - sometimes up to 10x. Plus you've just got to love the simplicity of the construction.